# R igraph partially filled vertex

Tags: r, plot, shapes, vertex, igraph

Given a vector of fractions(on the domain [0:1]), I want to plot the vertex just partially filled.
I.e. if the fraction is 1/2 the corresponding vertex should be half-filled(half-sphere)
I.e. if the fraction is 1/4 the corresponding vertex is only in one quarter (quarter-sphere)
and so forth...

```
library('igraph')
N <- 10
g <- graph.full(N)
values <- runif(N,0,1) # vector of fractions
V(g)$shape <-'circle'

plot.igraph(g,...)
```

for example:
http://www.google.ch/imgres?q=three+quarter-filled+circle&um=1&hl=de&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=751&tbm=isch&tbnid=fCz7FZ6JG38DzM:&imgrefurl=http://www.clipartstation.com/clipart_indexer4/index/search%3Fkeywords%3DART&docid=UPphGFugM1pYGM&imgurl=http://www.clipartstation.com/clipart/resized/Math/Transformations/__100x100//three%252520quarters%252520blue%252520circle.gif&w=100&h=99&ei=ETsNUNDeHbCL4gTT5rjACg&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=331&sig=101088608959992434501&page=1&tbnh=79&tbnw=80&start=0&ndsp=24&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:0,i:97&tx=49&ty=38

Comment: e.g.: http://www.google.ch/imgres?q=three+quarter-filled+circle&um=1&hl=de&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=751&tbm=isch&tbnid=fCz7FZ6JG38DzM:&imgrefurl=http://www.clipartstation.com/clipart_indexer4/index/search%3Fkeywords%3DART&docid=UPphGFugM1pYGM&imgurl=http://www.clipartstation.com/clipart/resized/Math/Transformations/__100x100//three%252520quarters%252520blue%252520circle.gif&w=100&h=99&ei=ETsNUNDeHbCL4gTT5rjACg&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=331&sig=101088608959992434501&page=1&tbnh=79&tbnw=80&start=0&ndsp=24&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:0,i:97&tx=49&ty=38

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `igraph` package version 0.6, you should be able to use the [pie](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/vertex.shape.pie.html) vertex in `plot()`, in which case your code would be:

```
library(igraph)
N <- 10
g <- graph.full(N)

values <- runif(N,0,1) # vector of fractions
plot(g, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values, vertex.frame.color="white", 
     vertex.pie.color=list(heat.colors(5)))
```

If you don't have this working (which I didn't), you can find the code [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2010-10/msg00079.html), which you can run and then use `pie` as a vertex.

Comment: Shouldn't `values` be a list of vectors, e.g., `values <- lapply( runif(N,0,1), function(u) c(u,1-u) )`?

Comment: @DiscreteCircle: Your solution doesn´t work on my igraph version either. But your hyperlink to the post from Gabor Csardi is good - works perfectly! THX

Comment: @Vincent Zoonekynd: You are right. If the pie shouldn´t be just in one color.